# Split the data present in different rows using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, split

Please help me with splitting the data.

Im having some data in my excel file as

```
123456 // row id 0,0
234567 // row id 1,0
345678 // row id 2,0
456789 // row id 3,0
```

and so on...

now i'm providing this data in textbox of windows application and want the output data as `split[0] = 123456,split[1]=234567` and so on...

Please help me with this...

```
string text = textBox1.Text;
string[] split = text.Split();//Here what condition should i give???
int count = split.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(split[i]);
}
```

Comment: It´s not clear to me what your actual file looks like, is `//`the delimier? Than use this one for your `Split`. Is it `,`? You may split every string you obtained from the split before using a loop.

Comment: Think it's not row id, it's cell id, so we have a single column of 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re only interested in the part before the `//` then you can also use another approach using `String.Substring()`:

```
int num;
if(int.TryParse(text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("//")), out num) {
    // do something with num
};
```

Alternativly using `Split`:

```
int num;
if(int.TryParse(text.Split("//")[0], out num) {
    // do something with num
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       string text = @"
        123456 // row id 0,0
          234567 // row id 1,0
         345678 // row id 2,0
           456789 // row id 3,0
        ";
        string[] splits = text.Split('\n');//Here what condition should i give???
      string[] split=new string[splits.Length];
      int j=0;
      foreach (var x in splits)
      {
          split[j]=x.Split(' ')[0];
              j++;
      }
        int count = split.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(split[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
  String text =
    @"123456 // row id 0,0
      234567 // row id 1,0
      345678 // row id 2,0
      456789 // row id 3,0";

  // new Char[] { '\r', '\n' }  - I don't know the actual separator
  // Regex.Match(...) - 1st integer number in the line
  int[] split = text
    .Split(new Char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => int.Parse(Regex.Match(line.TrimStart(), "^[0-9]+").Value))
    .ToArray();

  // Test: 
  // 123456
  // 234567
  // 345678
  // 456789
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, split));
```